# Get cell value from a pandas DataFrame row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a simple DataFrame and I need to be able to get the value of a specific cell. Here is a sample of my DataFrame:

```
     iata               name        city state country
2144  M15       Perry County      Linden    TN     USA
2391  N69         Stormville  Stormville    NY     USA
861   ARA  Acadiana Regional  New Iberia    LA     USA
2596  PDX      Portland Intl    Portland    OR     USA
3238  VES       Darke County  Versailles    OH     USA
```

As an example of what I am trying to do, I need to get the value of the `name` column for the row where the `iata` column equals 'PDX'. I can use `airports[airports.iata == 'PDX'].name` to retrieve the row I want:

```
2596    Portland Intl
Name: name, dtype: object
```

The question is now, how do I retrieve the *value* of the name cell for this row?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`.loc` returns series when you do boolean indexing because there are chances that you have multiple match cases.

```
df.loc[df.iata == 'PDX','name']

2596    Portland Intl
Name: name, dtype: object
```

If you want only the value then convert it to list and then access according to the index

```
df.loc[df.iata == 'PDX','name'].tolist()[0]
```

Or access based on the index in values i.e

```
df.loc[df.iata == 'PDX','name'].values[0]
```

Comment: ```.tolist()``` does not work with pandas dataframes ```.values[0]``` creates a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

Alternative ways to get the scalar values of a single value Series are:

```py
val = df.loc[df['iata'] == 'PDX', 'name'].squeeze()

val = df.loc[df['iata'] == 'PDX', 'name'].item()

val = df.loc[df['iata'] == 'PDX', 'name'].iat[0]
```

All of them return `'Portland Intl'`.